# How does MySQL WEEK(date[,mode]); work or what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: mysql, date

I need to get the starting and end date of a week for a given date.
I need the week of the given date to start on a monday.

If I run this query with out using the mode option.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20') YEAR,
       WEEK('2015-01-20') WK_No ,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20'), WEEK('2015-01-20'), 'Monday'), '%X%V %W') Mon,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20'), WEEK('2015-01-20'), 'Tuesday'), '%X%V %W') Tues,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20'), WEEK('2015-01-20'), 'Wednesday'), '%X%V %W') Wed,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20'), WEEK('2015-01-20'), 'Thursday'), '%X%V %W') Thur,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20'), WEEK('2015-01-20'), 'Friday'), '%X%V %W') Fri,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20'), WEEK('2015-01-20'), 'Saturday'), '%X%V %W') Sat,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20'), WEEK('2015-01-20'), 'Sunday'), '%X%V %W') Sun;
```

I get the following result

```
YEAR WK_No Mon          Tues        Wed         Thur        Fri         Sat         Sun
2015 3     2015-01-19   2015-01-20  2015-01-21  2015-01-22  2015-01-23  2015-01-24  2015-01-18
```

Here the week starts on Sun 18th

According to the mysql help
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

If I set the mode to 1, 3, 5, 7 my week should start on a Monday but none of them do
If I use modes 1 or 3 eg mode 1

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20') YEAR,
       WEEK('2015-01-20',1) WK_No ,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20'), WEEK('2015-01-20',1), 'Monday'), '%X%V %W') Mon,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20'), WEEK('2015-01-20',1), 'Tuesday'), '%X%V %W') Tues,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20'), WEEK('2015-01-20',1), 'Wednesday'), '%X%V %W') Wed,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20'), WEEK('2015-01-20',1), 'Thursday'), '%X%V %W') Thur,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20'), WEEK('2015-01-20',1), 'Friday'), '%X%V %W') Fri,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20'), WEEK('2015-01-20',1), 'Saturday'), '%X%V %W') Sat,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20'), WEEK('2015-01-20',1), 'Sunday'), '%X%V %W') Sun;
```

My results are so wrong its just not true

```
YEAR    WK_No   Mon         Tues        Wed         Thur        Fri         Sat         Sun
2015    4       2015-01-26  2015-01-27  2015-01-28  2015-01-29  2015-01-30  2015-01-31  2015-01-25
```

I get a week that does not include the date and the week still starts on a Sunday

If I use modes 5 or 7 eg mode 5

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20') YEAR,
       WEEK('2015-01-20',5) WK_No ,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20'), WEEK('2015-01-20',5), 'Monday'), '%X%V %W') Mon,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20'), WEEK('2015-01-20',5), 'Tuesday'), '%X%V %W') Tues,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20'), WEEK('2015-01-20',5), 'Wednesday'), '%X%V %W') Wed,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20'), WEEK('2015-01-20',5), 'Thursday'), '%X%V %W') Thur,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20'), WEEK('2015-01-20',5), 'Friday'), '%X%V %W') Fri,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20'), WEEK('2015-01-20',5), 'Saturday'), '%X%V %W') Sat,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20'), WEEK('2015-01-20',5), 'Sunday'), '%X%V %W') Sun;
```

I get the same result as without using the mode option.

```
YEAR WK_No Mon          Tues        Wed         Thur        Fri         Sat         Sun
2015 3     2015-01-19   2015-01-20  2015-01-21  2015-01-22  2015-01-23  2015-01-24  2015-01-18
```

How do I get the starting and end date of a week for a given date.
with the week of the given date to starting on a Monday?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to find the start and end day of the week, monday and sunday respectively, for the date you provide as input..

This can be done rather a lot easier than you are trying to do right now using the DATE_ADD and SUBDATE functions.

For more information about these functions take a look at [the documentation.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday)

With these queries you can make a function to handle this for you. DATE() might work instead of the casting, will look into it when i'm home.

**Next sunday of the Week:**

`SELECT CAST('2015-04-22' + INTERVAL (6-WEEKDAY('2015-04-22')) day AS DATE);`

**Start of the Week:**

`SELECT CAST(SUBDATE('2015-04-26', WEEKDAY('2015-04-26')) AS DATE);`

edit: was a bit too quick to react, edited the queries, the end of the week might be a bit overcomplicated, I'll look into it when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer why the original query was wrong: You're using `STR_TO_DATE` with `%X%V %W` as format mask which uses the provided week number to transform the string into the correct date. However, this function needs to know about your 'week start' as well.

According to [DATE_FORMAT docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) there are the following options:

```
%V  Week (01..53), where Sunday is the first day of the week; WEEK() mode 2; used with %X
%v  Week (01..53), where Monday is the first day of the week; WEEK() mode 3; used with %x
```

Hence, you should use for example `STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015-01-20'), WEEK('2015-01-20',1), 'Monday'), '%x%v %W') Mon` to let the week start on Monday.